Value cannot be null (parameter 'type')
I have been using sqlite-net-pcl nuget for my MAUI project. I want to get the return type as list of objects. I didn't know what Model the result is. I want the result is like list of object like datasets. Is there a way to get this done by using this same nuget in MAUI?
I have tried,
public partial class DatabaseContext
{
    private const string DbName = "MycustomSqlite.s3db";
    private static string DbPath => Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, DbName);

    private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection = null!;
    private SQLiteAsyncConnection Database =>
      (_connection ??= new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DbPath,
          SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache));

    public async Task<List<object>> GetParamList()
    {
        try
        {
            List<object> LstParams = new List<object>();
            string sqlquery = "select ParamID,ParamValue,DefaultValue, ParamName from Parametername";
            LstParams = await Database.QueryAsync<object>(sqlquery);
            return LstParams;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

MycustomSqlite.s3db is my customized sqlite data that has Parametername Table.
From this code i got this error,
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type')
   at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
   at System.ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Object argument, String paramName)
   at System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(Type type)
   at SQLite.TableMapping.GetPublicMembers(Type type)
   at SQLite.TableMapping..ctor(Type type, CreateFlags createFlags)
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.GetMapping(Type type, CreateFlags createFlags)
   at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQuery[Object]()
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Query[Object](String query, Object[] args) 


What do you mean you don’t know what the type is?

We need to see the full stack trace from the exception. What you show here almost certainly isn't the issue. What is Database and how is it setup/configured?

@Jason, I Altered this question of better clarification.  I don't want to pass the Model for the result in queryasync, I just want that result as a list of object.

@DavidG , I altered the question and code for better understanding.

You need to create a model for your query type. You can't use just object.
For example:
public class ParamList
{
    public int ParamID { get; set: }
    public int ParamValue { get; set; }
    public int DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public string ParamName { get; set; }
}

Note that I made some guesses on the datatypes. Fix accordingly.
Then update your list datatype and method return:
public async Task<List<ParamList>> GetParamList()
{
    try
    {
        var lstParams = new List<ParamList>();
        string sqlquery = "select ParamID,ParamValue,DefaultValue, ParamName from Parametername";
        lstParams = await Database.QueryAsync<ParamList>(sqlquery);
        return lstParams;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

Also, it's been a hot minute since I've used the library, but I believe that QueryAsync returns an IEnumerable, so you may need to call .ToList() on it.
Make sure to review the documentation when using a new library. The author explicitly states near the bottom of this section:

The generic parameter to the Query method specifies the type of object
to create for each row. It can be one of your table classes, or any
other class whose public properties match the column returned by the
query

